# Inequality in 4 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I came across the following problem in a book. Four real numbers $p,q,r,s$ satisfy $p+q+r+s=9$ and $p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2=21$. Prove that there is a permutation  $a,b,c,d$ of $p,q,r,s$ Such that $ab-cd\ge 2$. First I ordered $p\ge q\ge r\ge s$. One immediate result is $pq+pr+ps+qr+qs+rs=30$. We know that $$(p^2+r^2)(q^2+s^2)=(pq-rs)^2+(ps+qr)^2$$ Now $p\ge q$ and $r\ge s$. Therefore $p^2+q^2\ge r^2+s^2$.  What should I do after this?

Comment: I think you did a mistake in your immediate result. I think it is $pq+pr+ps+qr+qs+rs=15$.

Comment: @Martigan -- $(9^2-21)/2=30$ should be same as half of $(p+q+r+s)^2-(p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2)$, which is the sum of the products.

Comment: @coffeemath $(p+q+r+s)^2=81=p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2+2(pq+pr+ps+qr+qs+rs)$, hence $pq+pr+ps+qr+qs+rs=\dfrac{81-21}{2}$. In fact it is $30$, not $15$ like in my comment... Definitely not $6$.

Comment: @Martigan...sorry for the mistake...I have edited it..

Comment: Does the problem say anything about the signs? I.e. are $p,q,r,s$ assumed positive, or maybe nonnegative?

Comment: @coffeemath  All need to be positive.  If $s \le 0$, then $p+q+r \ge 9 \implies p^2+q^2+r^2 \ge 27$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that $$2(x^{2}+y^{2})=(x+y)^{2}+(x-y)^{2}$$. then

$$\Longrightarrow 84=4(p^{2}+q^{2}+r^{2}+s^{2})=(p+q+r+s)^{2}+(p+q-r-s)^{2}+(p+r-q-s)^{2}+(p+s-q-r)^{2}$$

this implies that $$\Longrightarrow (p+q-r-s)^{2}+(p+r-q-s)^{2}+(p+s-q-r)^{2}=3$$ then

$$\max\{|p+q-r-s|,|p+r-q-s|,|p+s-q-r|\}\geq 1$$.

suppose wlog that $|p+q-r-s|\geq 1$, then this implies that

$2(p+q)-9=p+q-r-s\geq 1$ or $2(r+s)-9=r+s-p-q\geq 1$

the first case implies that $p+q\geq 5$, while the second that $r+s\geq 5$. suppose wlog that $p+q\geq 5$

then, $$\Longrightarrow 21+2(pq-rs)=(p+q)^{2}+(r-s)^{2}\geq 25$$ from where we conclude that $$pq-rs\geq 2$$

Comment: Amazing!!! I also found that we only have to prove $(p+q)^2+(r-s)^2\ge 25$, but couldn't do anything more with that. +1